# Is this an implicit pipe?

Tags: bash, ubuntu, pipe

Consider:

```
./wordcount.py < war_and_peace.txt | sort -grk 2 | head
```

To my surprise, the following works as well and produces the same output:

```
./wordcount.py < war_and_peace.txt sort -grk 2 | head
```

How is the latter command interpreted? Is piping to `sort` happening implicitly?

Comment: If it produces the same output, it's because the `sort` is unnecessary. Dropping the `|` just makes `sort`, `-grk`, and `2` additional arguments to `wordcount.py`, which ignores them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> s this an implicit pipe?

No.

> How is the latter command interpreted?

The same as

```
./wordcount.py sort -grk 2 < war_and_peace.txt | head
```

or

```
< war_and_peace.txt ./wordcount.py sort -grk 2 | head
```

or

```
./wordcount.py sort -grk < war_and_peace.txt 2 | head
```

A `./wordcount.py` command is run with 3 arguments - string `sort`, string `-grk` and string `2` with standard input redirected from `war_and_peace.txt` file. The output of the command is redirected to the input of command `head`.

The placement of `<` followed by filename between the command arguments does not matter. It's typical to place is as the last. I like to start commands with `<` as the first argument, as it's the input, but some people find it confusing.